# checkbox values true or false alternative to string in cshtml

Tags: c#, html, razor, checkbox

Is there an alternative and more "correct" method to turn the value of a checkbox into a bool.

My cshtml code:

```
@{
    Page.Title = "";
    Layout = "~/_Layout.cshtml";

    bool checked = false;

    if(isPost)
    {
        if(Request["chkbx"] == "on")
        {
            checked = true;
        }
    }
}

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbx" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, create a strongly typed view and let the model binding do it.

Comment: can I convince you to show me an example?

Comment: thats actually a bad example, one sec, googling more. EDIT: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx

Comment: The problem is you're doing a bunch of stuff in your view (like checking if is post) and getting the request value of the checkbox that you shouldn't be. You need to do that stuff in your controller. I recommend picking up an mvc book

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.NET MVC Razor views in general aren't supposed to mess with things like `Request`.

It's up to the `Controller` to create a `ViewModel` object from the `Request` (using `ModelBinding` preferably) then passing the created object to the `View`.

Yet, if you're reluctant on changing course to the `ViewModel` path:

You can use built in HTML Helpers for Razor:
`@Html.CheckBox("chkbx", checked)`

Alternatively, if you prefer to code your HTML elements manually, this might look cleaner:
`<input type="checkbox" name="chkbx" @(checked ? "checked" : "") />`